# Review audits should be weighted towards tags user is familiar with

Tags: feature-request

It seems more logical to have review queues weighted towards tags a user is familiar with. Would this be an appropriate addition to the review system?

Comment: You can *already* filter the queues on tags. The rest are not nearly busy enough to filter, and you can always skip posts you don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *already* a part of several of the review queues.  While they don't *prohibit* you from reviewing content out of your tag, they attempt to give you posts in tags you're active in to the best of their ability.